# How to get the public IP address for OBS Studio when streaming to MediaLive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, live-streaming, aws-media-live, obs-studio

I am trying to send my live stream from OBS Studio to AWS MediaLive. I found [this](https://d2908q01vomqb2.cloudfront.net/fb644351560d8296fe6da332236b1f8d61b2828a/2020/04/14/Connecting-OBS-Studio-to-AWS-Media-Services-in-the-Cloud-v2.pdf) workflow example. But in the prerequisites section, it says:

> You need the public IP address (or addresses) from the appliance that you are using to send the feed
> to the AWS Elemental MediaLive input.

How to obtain this IP address?

Comment: Go to a search engine (Google, Bing, DuckDuckGo, etc.) and type `what is my IP address`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried this. My IP address is something like xx.xxx.xx.xxx but MediaLive wants a CIDR formatted string, how to convert my ip address into cidr format?

Comment: CIDR format for a single IPv4 address just means adding `/32` to the end of it. That means only a single IP address. (For example, `/24` would mean "the entire block of addresses around mine, from `x.x.x.0` to `x.x.x.255`. `/0` would mean "the entire Internet".)